# How to run CI on gitlab.com with only and except condition?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to trigger a CI job for my repository which is hosted on Gitlab.com, when a new version is released. Versions are released by creating a (version) git tag that follows semantic versioning, e.g. `v4.0.1` ...

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` I am using:

```
release:
  script: ...
  only:
    - /^v.*$/
  except:
    - branches
    - triggers
```

and in my code I am doing:

```
git tag v4.0.2
git push origin v4.0.2
```

But the pipelines remain silent.

When removing the `only` and `except` conditionals every commit triggers a pipeline run - but this is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So If I understood correcly you want to execute your CI only for git tags.
This can be done easily by using

```
only:
    - tags@yourgroup/yourproject
```

with this condition the gitlab CI will be triggered only for tags.